# MongoDB Java Driver - $in select query running slowly

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I am using Java Driver to query a MongoDB instance and experiencing poor read performance. My table isn't especially large with about 30m records. I have been trying queries of varying size, I haven't got anything above 200k to return within a reasonable time, and 200k takes about 5-10 minutes.

MongoDB logs for the query:

2017-12-15T01:13:10.877+0000 I COMMAND [conn3] command db.events command: getMore { getMore: 23973717840, collection: "events", batchSize: 10000 } originatingCommand: { find: "events", filter: { id: { $in: [ ] } }, batchSize: 10000 } planSummary: IXSCAN { id: 1 } cursorid:23973717840 keysExamined:10000 docsExamined:10000 fromMultiPlanner:1 numYields:79 nreturned:10000 reslen:7280007 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 160 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 80 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 80 } } } protocol:op_query 124ms

2017-12-15T01:13:14.214+0000 I COMMAND [conn3] command db.events command: getMore { getMore: 23973717840, collection: "events", batchSize: 10000 } originatingCommand: { find: "events", filter: { id: { $in: [ ] } }, batchSize: 10000 } planSummary: IXSCAN { id: 1 } cursorid:23973717840 keysExamined:10001 docsExamined:10000 fromMultiPlanner:1 numYields:79 nreturned:10000 reslen:7240971 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 160 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 80 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 80 } } } protocol:op_query 114ms

2017-12-15T01:13:18.646+0000 I COMMAND [conn3] command db.events command: getMore { getMore: 23973717840, collection: "events", batchSize: 10000 } originatingCommand: { find: "events", filter: { id: { $in: [ ] } }, batchSize: 10000 } planSummary: IXSCAN { id: 1 } cursorid:23973717840 keysExamined:10000 docsExamined:10000 fromMultiPlanner:1 numYields:81 nreturned:10000 reslen:7217981 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 164 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 82 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 82 } } } protocol:op_query 172ms

2017-12-15T01:15:39.565+0000 I COMMAND [conn3] command db.events command: getMore { getMore: 23973717840, collection: "events", batchSize: 10000 } originatingCommand: { find: "events", filter: { id: { $in: [ ] } }, batchSize: 10000 } planSummary: IXSCAN { id: 1 } cursorid:23973717840 keysExamined:10001 docsExamined:10000 fromMultiPlanner:1 numYields:79 nreturned:10000 reslen:7252405 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 160 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 80 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 80 } } } protocol:op_query 165ms

I have profiled my Java code:

[image]

I am not doing anything non-standard elsewhere (using forEach to loop through FindIterable with Consumer) so I am not sure how it could be Java...but the logs suggest that it couldn't be anything else but Java.

My table has indexes on the relevant columns. I have removed the content of $in. I have optimised my table structure as far as possible (I believe). Might this be some kind of RAM issue?

Before anyone asks, I am unable to do something a different way. This query seems pretty simple, using a smaller length of in (for example, 5) returns quicker but is too slow for my application.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: db.events.find( { id: { $in: [ ] } })  is the only query you're using?

Comment: Yes. I have removed the actual content of $in because it is several hundred items long. $in is querying an indexed key.

Comment: The log say that it takes 165ms to execute such query. Does adding content to $in query adds up-to slowness?

Comment: Yes. This is explained in the first paragraph but: anything returning over 200k records doesn't finish, 200k takes 5-10 minutes, and I can do 1000 at a time (the smallest possible unit for my application) but the overall speed is nowhere near fast enough for my application (this is unrelated to calculations within the code).

Comment: Can you add the explain plan with the $in content filled? How much data size is this? How much memory is allocated? How many cores are in this server?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you mean. The $in, I think had above is between 500-1000 items. There are about 1500 items per item in $in, so just under 1m records. As I say, it was running with 200k records but too slowly. The total table is ~40m records, ~6GB. Mongo is running on a 2-core, 2GB server. Obviously, Java is using a ton of memory anyway but I actually tried to run the same query in Python and it was using about 8gb on the client...so I am assuming it must be memory?

Comment: You could try using projection and/or lower batch size to check how that would affect slowliness.

Comment: Okay, my index is 1.25gb...so too large for a 2gb server? I can't use projection. I tried lowering batch size, I think there is some slight improvement but not enough :)